# Ruby: having callbacks on 'attr' objects

Tags: ruby, callback

Essentially I'm wondering how to place callbacks on objects in ruby, so that when an object is changed in anyway I can automatically trigger other changes:

(EDIT: I confused myself in my own example! Not a good sign… As @proxy is a URI object it has it's own methods, changing the URI object by using it's own methods doesn't call my own `proxy=` method and update the @http object)

```
class MyClass
  attr_reader :proxy
  def proxy=(string_proxy = "")
    begin
      @proxy = URI.parse("http://"+((string_proxy.empty?) ? ENV['HTTP_PROXY'] : string_proxy))
      @http = Net::HTTP::Proxy.new(@proxy.host,@proxy.port)
    rescue
      @http = Net::HTTP
    end
  end
end

m = MyClass.new
m.proxy = "myproxy.com:8080"
p m.proxy
# => <URI: @host="myproxy.com" @port=8080>

m.proxy.host = 'otherproxy.com'
p m.proxy
# => <URI: @host="otherproxy.com" @port=8080>
# But accessing a website with @http.get('http://google.com') will still travel through myproxy.com as the @http object hasn't been changed when m.proxy.host was.
```

Comment: What do you mean "as proxy= is not being called"? Of course it's called.

Comment: I don't understand, you do get `Net::HTTP`...? You can check it if you add an `attr_reader :http` and inspect `p m.http`. What do you mean `proxy=` is not called when `m.proxy` is changed? That function call is the only thing that happens - you can't directly change instance variables in Ruby.

Comment: Ahh pants, I confused myself in my example! The `proxy=` method won't be called if daughter objects of the @proxy URI object are changed (see the last 4 lines of my example code) - hope this makes more sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure this one out for myself!

```
# Unobtrusive modifications to the Class class.
class Class
  # Pass a block to attr_reader and the block will be evaluated in the context of the class instance before
  # the instance variable is returned.
  def attr_reader(*params,&block)
    if block_given?
      params.each do |sym|
        # Create the reader method
        define_method(sym) do
          # Force the block to execute before we…
         self.instance_eval(&block)
          # … return the instance variable
          self.instance_variable_get("@#{sym}")
        end
      end
    else # Keep the original function of attr_reader
      params.each do |sym|
        attr sym
      end
    end
  end
end
```

If you add that code somewhere it'll extend the `attr_reader` method so that if you now do the following:

```
attr_reader :special_attr { p "This happens before I give you @special_attr" }
```

It'll trigger the block before it gives you the `@special_attr`. It's executed in the instance scope so you can use it, for example, in classes where attributes are downloaded from the internet. If you define a method like `get_details` which does all retrieval and sets `@details_retrieved` to `true` then you can define the attr like this:

```
attr_reader :name, :address, :blah { get_details if @details_retrieved.nil? }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your line `m.proxy = nil` will raise a `NoMethodError` exception, since `nil` does no respond to `empty?`. Thus `@http` is set to `Net::HTTP`, as in the rescue clause.

This has nothing to do with callbacks/setters. You should modify your code to do what you want (e.g. calling `string_proxy.blank?` if using activesupport).

Comment: Sorry about that, I managed to confuse myself and ask the wrong question (I simplified my code to bring it onto stackoverflow) — thanks for your help though!